# /How to get active Tab url in safari browser using java script

Tags: javascript, url, safari-extension

How to get the browser window or active tab url using java script in a safari browser ?

I tried to do it using ->

document.url

window.location.href

But both this solutions are giving me so many urls . I dont know why ?

Also I have searched that safari.application.browserWindow.activeTab gives obj of current active window . But I dont know which methods are provided by activeTab class

If anyone knows , plz help me . Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by "so many URLs"? You need to show what's returned by both the methods you've tried. Also, typing "please" out in full wouldn't hurt.

Comment: show this url for finding the solution:: http://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#documentation/Tools/Conceptual/SafariExtensionGuide/WorkingwithWindowsandTabs/WorkingwithWindowsandTabs.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009977-CH17-SW1

Comment: please ignore the previous comment..                               it is showing different url twice like facebook.com then it shows the original url. On every browser it loads for 3 times nd giv us a 3 different url. I want to make plugin so i want exact url which we entered as url link. Give me the solution that how i can fetch the url from browser.                                                  http://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#documentation/Tools/Conceptual/SafariExtensionGuide/WorkingwithWindowsandTabs/WorkingwithWindowsandTabs.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009977-CH17-SW1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you just want the URL of the "top" document in the current tab, you can use

```
safari.application.activeBrowserWindow.activeTab.url
```

from within your extension's global page.

The properties and methods of the SafariBrowserTab class are given here: https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#documentation/UserExperience/Reference/SBrowserTabClassReference/SafariBrowserTab.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009793

I infer from your question that your extension is using an injected script, which is reporting the URL of the page in which it is being run to the global page. Your global page is receiving multiple URLs because the injected script is running not only in the "top" document of the tab, but also in every iframed document inside it.

If you want to prevent the injected script from running inside iframes, wrap the code in a statement like this:

```
if (window == window.top) {
    // do stuff
}
```