# Is there an equivalent to chrome.windows.getCurrent in Safari?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, safari-extension

The Chrome API provides a method to get the current window [`chrome.windows.getCurrent`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/windows#method-getCurrent) (return the window that contains the code that is currently executing). Is there an equivalent method in Safari?

Comment: [activeBrowserWindow](https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/documentation/UserExperience/Reference/SafariApplicationClassRef/index.html#//apple_ref/javascript/instp/SafariApplication/activeBrowserWindow)?

Comment: @wOxxOm It depends on what they mean by "active". Chrome explicitly says that `getCurrent` doesn't necessarily return the [topmost/focused window](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/windows#current-window). I feel like activeBrowserWindow simply returns the window that's currently in focus.

Comment: Please check solution given in this related SO post - [How to get active Tab url in safari browser using java script](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12130070/how-to-get-active-tab-url-in-safari-browser-using-java-script).

Answer (score 0):

At least you can get it from background script:
safari.application.activeBrowserWindow.activeTab

That works for current window/tab with focus.